# Using Display:Block; and Display:None in the Same HTML Document

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make two piece of code to work in the same HTML document (in by Blogger Blog). However, due to lack of knowledge, I am unable to do so.

Both piece of code works great when they are inputted into different HTML pages. However, if they are inserted into a single HTML page, it either displays no headline from the code 1 or title in the code 2.

The two piece of code are as follows.

Code 1: Here I only want to display the headline (title) and not the content of the post.

```
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/JobsInSports?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
    div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li {
      list-style-type: decimal;
    }
    div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li span.headline { 
      font-weight:bold; 
      display:block; 
      margin:12px 0 0 0; 
    }
</style>
```

Code 2: Here I only want to appear the content of the post and not the title of the post (headline).

```
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/VacancyInAssamGoogle?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
    div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li {
      list-style-type: decimal;
    }
    div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li span.headline { 
      font-weight:bold; 
      display:none;
      margin:12px 0 0 0; 
    }
</style>
```

Comment: What's the question here? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is the problem you are seeing? Where did you get these snippets from? What are they expected to do? What is happening now which is different from the expectation? Check out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and consider updating your question so people can understand your problem and answer better :)

Comment: Sir, I have just updated the question to make it more understandable. I hope I able to convey what I supposed to do.

Comment: The difference in the appearance between both code blocks is the `display` property of the element `div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li span.headline`, `none` for not displaying it and `block` to display it. With the amount of information you are providing I will advise you choosing only one way to display it and avoid all the code repetition. Also don't know what does the `<script>` tag does or how all this is generated. Hope it helps. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Sir, yes, you are right. I have tried. However,  it either display no headline from the code 1 or title in the code 2. I am posting my blog website address here so that you can know. http:// www. vacancyinassam. com (fragmented). I want to hide the title in the main content area so that my traffic dont go to Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to either of the code blocks under the style tag will hide links to twitter in the main content

```css
#main a[href^="https://twitter"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Also remove the `display: none;` from Code 2:

```
div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li span.headline { 
  font-weight:bold; 
  display:none; /* << remove this line */
  margin:12px 0 0 0; 
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Hurray. So nice of you. Its work perfectly. Thanks a ton sir.

Comment: @BadanBarman Glad to be helpful, check the question as solved if it worked for you.

Comment: Sir, I have not found any option to mark the question as "Solved" or "Answered", even I am unable to vote. I think it is hidden for the new members!